# C++ HTTP Request using cpprestdk always exception. no symbols loaded for cpprest142_2_10d.dll

Tags: c++, http, https

Good day everyone. I am kinda new in using C++ and I want to make a request using C++. I tried using curl, c++ request and all of that but sadly I have no clue how to set it up in Microsoft Visual Studio so I just tried cpprestsdk. I have gone to the point where I can send a request then see its response but after that it always makes this exception. Anyone knows how to fix this?

> <Information not available, no symbols loaded for cpprest142_2_10d.dll>

Comment: thats just a message from the debugger that you don't have the debug symbols for the library, its not an error

Comment: @AlanBirtles so when in production it is okay to ignore this?

Comment: Does that mean there is really no problem with the program just during executing it in debug mode? @AlanBirtles

Comment: No idea, that message in itself isn't a problem unless you want to debug cpprest itself